# OpenCover under the hood

Tags: c#, .net, opencover

I use OpenCover and it works fine for most of the cases. But I have one case when it doesn't understand that some piece of code is in use by tests. The case is when I execute something using Assembly.Load(). Something like this

```
var assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyBytes);
var sut = assembly.GetType("ClassToTest");
var methodToTest = sut.GetMethod("MethodToTest", Binding.Static | ...);
methodToTest.Invoke(null, ...)
```

Now I am interested in OpenCover details to try make the example working. I know that OpenCover uses Mono.Cecil and Profiling API but it doesn't say much to me without other details.

Comment: https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover

Comment: Yeah, I know. But there they ask to use SO for questions

Comment: https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover/issues/950